# When should we use dp or sp in layout?

Tags: android, layout, view

I created an android app that looks perfect on large screens. But the view gets distorted or in other terms the upper and bottom parts get cut off on smaller screens. I used sp and dp interchangably without me knowing they are different, if not same. I used sp for fonts and dp for dimensions as a rule. But this didn't work. What is the difference between sp and dp and when to use what?  Thanks in advance.
The xml layout file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tempLabel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#CC66FF"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.coolweather.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actualTemp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hundred"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="150sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/degreeImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/actualTemp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actualTemp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/degree" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cityLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cloudy" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/summary"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="Pleasant cool day with flowers!" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/degreeImageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/actualTemp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/humidityLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Humidity"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/humidity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="80%"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
         android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/precLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Rain/Snow"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prcip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="100%"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/actualTemp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="At 5:00pm it will be"
    android:textColor="#80FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cityLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeLabel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:text="Roorkee"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

<ProgressBar
   android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageIcon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/refreshImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/refresh" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between px, dp, dip and sp in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Comment: `dp` is used for general layout, `sp` is used for fonts.

Comment: `sp` or "scalable pixels" are used for text. `dp` or "density independent pixels" are used for layouting.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I needed answer to my layout problem. please comment according to the question.

Comment: why have you given `textSize` **150sp** in textview `id=actualTemp`? Maybe its the reason because your layout is not scrollable  and you have given very big font size

Comment: This I have done by purpose... but my doubt is if the layout appears properly on large screens then why not it appears properly in small screens.. Is there a way to universalize the layout view which would fit properly in all screens.....

Comment: If you have other question about other topics, please create a new question instead of editing the content of this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android recommends to use `sp` when you are setting **font size** and `dp` for everything else like width, length, height, margin, padding

Comment: I used sp for fonts and dp for dimensions... but still the layout is distorted

Comment: @NagabhushanBaddi Then please edit your question and add your layout which crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them for anything : heights, margins, font size, etc.

The difference is that `dp` is a fixed unit and  `sp` will be scaled according to the phone font size settings.

Comment: IF i use sp everywhere does my above problem get solved

Answer (score 0):

`sp` is the recommended unit for font sizes because a user may enable low-visibility settings to increase font sizes on the device.

`dp` is a physical unit of measurement to translate screen resolution into a real world size. `dp` is calculated as `resolution / density`, where `density` is 1.0 for an mdpi screen (160dpi) and scaled accordingly based on dpi (ie. an xxhdpi screen of 480 dpi will have a density of 3.0). `dp` is used for all other physical elements that you wish to take up a fixed, real world size.

You need to post your layout code for us to figure out why it is getting cut off on smaller screens rather than larger ones. It is most likely because you are defining a fixed layout height/width (ie. 600 dp) which will appear fine on a tablet (which generally have minimum widths of at least 600 dp) but most phones in portrait mode will have a width of 360 dp.